Escaping rules for strings containing scripts through SSH
I'm trying to send a PowerShell script as a string through SSH in PowerShell 5.1. Its objective is to modify the content of a configuration file in a remote computer. I managed to fix the problems relating to escaping the special character sequences thanks to this answer in my previous question. However, I assumed that ssh $Username@$ComputerIP $stringScript would execute similarly to cmd.exe /c $stringScript but from my testing it doesn't, they are processed differently at a level I don't understand, as the code with ssh gives an error.
Here's my intended code:
$forceOnlyKeysSSH = '`nMatch all`n`tPasswordAuthentication no'
$rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys = "powershell Add-Content -Force -Verbose -Path c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config " +
    "-Value \`"$forceOnlyKeysSSH\`""
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $Username@$ComputerIP $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys

Ideally it would modify the sshd_config file with
Match all
    PasswordAuthentication no

But I'm getting this error, that to me suggest is dividing the arguments around the spaces.
Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'all
        PasswordAuthentication'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Content -Force -Verbose -Path c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config -Val ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

Am I wrongly escaping the string? Why does this error not show up when calling cmd.exe /c $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys?



If you're calling ssh.exe from Windows PowerShell or PowerShell 7 v7.2.x or below, you unfortunately need to compensate for a bug that affects arguments with embedded " characters.

It so happens that the bug is canceled out when cmd.exe /c is called directly, due to cmd.exe's own parsing quirks.

All other external programs are affected, however, including ssh.exe.

Therefore, with a default SSH server configuration on Windows, even though the command passed to the ssh.exe client is ultimately passed to cmd /c, the bug must be dealt with.

See the workaround below.





This bug is fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7 versions 7.3 and above, so no additional effort is required when calling from there.

See this answer for background information.



Workaround:
Specifically, in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7.2- you must manually \-escape " chars. (double quotes) that are embedded in arguments.
Here's a cross-edition solution that applies the manual escaping only when needed:
$forceOnlyKeysSSH = '`nMatch all`n`tPasswordAuthentication no'
$rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys = "powershell -NoProfile Add-Content -Force -Verbose -Path c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config " +
    "-Value \`"$forceOnlyKeysSSH\`""
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt '7.3') { # Workaround needed
  # Manually add another round of \-escaping to the embedded, escaped \" chars.
  $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys = $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys.Replace('\"', '\\\"')
}
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $Username@$ComputerIP $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys

Note:

As written, the value stored in $forceOnlyKeysSSH is subject to whitespace normalization, so that, e.g.,
foo      bar would be passed as foo bar; that is, runs of two or more spaces are collapsed into a single space each.

If that is a concern, more work is needed, as detailed in the answer to your previous question - note that the need for the additional manual \-escaping equally applies situationally; to spell out the - more cumbersome - solution without whitespace normalization:
$forceOnlyKeysSSH = '`nMatch all`n`tPasswordAuthentication no'
# Note the (escaped) "..." enclosure around the (implied) -Command argument
# and the (escaped) "^""..."^"" enclosure around $forceOnlyKeysSSH
$rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys = "powershell -NoProfile `"Add-Content -Force -Verbose -Path c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config " +
    "-Value `"^`"`"$forceOnlyKeysSSH`"^`"`"`""
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt '7.3') { # Workaround needed
  # Manually add another round of \-escaping to the embedded " chars.
  $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys = $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys.Replace('"', '\"')
}
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $Username@$ComputerIP $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys




Even with the additional escaping around $forceOnlyKeysSSH and at the start of the command, the proposed changes result in the same error message as shown in the question Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument.... Also, the goal is that the string inside $forceOnlyKeysSSH keeps its format, so how is it possible to avoid the *whitespace normalization? Otherwise, the cross-edition solution looks very useful.

@JackOA, the solution that avoids whitespace normalization is in the 2nd code snippet in this answer, at the bottom. I'm surprised that it doesn't work, but I'll investigate (need to set up an SSH server on Windows).

@JackOA, I've set up an SSH server on Windows, and both code snippets in this answer work for me as advertised when calling from PowerShell. Are you sure you've used the code exactly as shown?

Nevermind, I misread the condition as being executed for versions newer than 7.3. It  actually does work successfully. However I'm not sure I fully understand the addition of ^. To clarify the answer, as it's quite complex escaping, could you describe what the string in $rmtPSAuthOnlyKeys would look like after each pass of parsing by PowerShell and Windows command line?

@JackOA, the ^ is there for cmd.exe's sake, and gets stripped before PowerShell sees it. The unescaped sequence that cmd.exe needs to see is "^"" for each embedded " inside overall "...". This makes Windows PowerShell see """, which it recognizes as an escaped, pass-through ". In PowerShell 7, "" is enough, and requires no use of ^.

@JackOA: The reason for the ^ is to ensure that cmd.exe sees the value between the embedded escaped double quotes as double-quoted too, which ensures that the command doesn't break if that value contains cmd.exe metacharacters such as &. See this answer for details.

Take the accepted answer by @mklement0 as the best approach.
As I tried on my own different escaping formats, I found that escaping the whitespace with ` in $forceOnlyKeysSSH did also result in the intended outcome without throwing any errors. I'm not quite sure how it work or if it's scalable, but requires less changes to the original code.
$forceOnlyKeysSSH = '`nMatch` all`n`tPasswordAuthentication` no'


You actually only need to escape spaces if there are two or more in sequence.
